# Asymmetric benchmarks in JMH

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I'm running performance tests on a custom collection implementation with JMH.

I'd like to imitate a scenario, where number of reads is 10x bigger than number of writes.

I used [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_15_Asymmetric.java) asymmetric benchmark example and created a group with 10 reader threads and 1 writer thread:

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Group("g0")
@GroupThreads(1)       
public void baselinePut0(CacheState0 state) { writing }

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Group("g0")
@GroupThreads(10)
public Integer baselineGet0(CacheState0 state) { reading }
```

I run the test with `-wi 10 -i 10 -f 1` params. In a report, variable `cnt` is same for all benchmarks:

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt     Score      Error  Units
Benchmark.g0               avgt   10   262,537 ?  215,406  us/op
Benchmark.g0:baselineGet0  avgt   10     2,101 ?    0,154  us/op
Benchmark.g0:baselinePut0  avgt   10  1252,231 ?  697,807  us/op
```

Does it mean that number of reads was equal to number of writes in the experiment? If so, how to implement it correctly? And more general: am I missing something in this setup?

Comment: Unless you *really* need to get the separate measurements for reads/writes, I would rather go with a symmetric (randomized) test that throws the ThreadLocalRandom-backed dice if it should do a read or a write. This way you are balancing the operation mix more carefully, and do not depend on thread scheduling. You don't run on the machine that can accommodate 11 running threads without stepping on each other, are you? ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Cnt` shows number of samples (not number of threads). In your case it's 10, since you are running your test with `-i 10`. It will be easier to see that this parameter is not number of threads if you run it with all params set to unique values (e.g. `-i 13`, while `@GroupThreads(10)` remains the same)

You can also (temporary) add the output line to your test and see where each thread is coming from, e.g. for reader (and similar for writer with the word "writer"):

```
System.out.println("reader " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Comment: that means number of reads was 10 and number of writes was 10. do you know how to achieve the goal I desribed in a question?

Comment: Cnt is not number of reads/writes, it's number of samples. You don't know the number of reads/writes, since Mode.AverageTime will do as many operations as it can [within time limit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_02_BenchmarkModes.java)

But thinking again, I do find that `Cnt` in your case should be 100, so maybe you forgot to provide the number of threads, i.e. `@Threads(11)` on top of class or `-t 11` as command line parameter? If you didn't, test would run with 1 thread in total (I think) as default

Comment: You correctly get 10 samples for either subtest, because iteration samples are also (in "avgt" mode) averaged across participating threads. So, on every iteration "put" test gets a sample from a single thread, and "get" test gets a sample averaged across 10 threads. With 10 iterations, you get 10 samples in both subtests. This is pretty much the same as with multithreaded "throughput" tests: a sample per iteration is a sum throughput across all threads.